# Play! upload images and make them available in production at /assets/images

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

[From the docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/AssetsOverview):

> When you package your application, all assets for the application, including all sub projects, are aggregated into a single jar, in target/my-first-app-1.0.0-assets.jar. This jar is included in the distribution so that your Play application can serve them. This jar can also be used to deploy the assets to a CDN or reverse proxy.

I got a few image uploads in my application, everything works fine in development but in production it gives me errors.

The thing is, I need those files in the public/images folder in order to display them on the page but it does not work in production.

How can I let the user upload images and also make them available at /public/images ?

Do I have to create another Assets path or something like that ?

note: Didn't post code because it's just a standard upload method from the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did:

I'm aware of the fact that this might be just a stupid workaround.

```
GET         /images/:name                               controllers.ImageController.show(name: String)
```

I created a simple action that serves the images like:

```
def show(name: String) = Action { implicit r =>
    val rootPath = Play.application.path
    val path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("/" + rootPath + "/public/images/");
    Logger.info("serving image: " + path.toString  + "/" + name )
    Ok.sendFile(new java.io.File(path.toString + "/" + name))
  }
```

Basically this whole operation will fail in development but it works in production.

After deployment, I created the folders manually e.g

```
 your_root/target/universal/stage/public/images
```

Now all the images are available at:

```
 /images/name_of_the_image
```

note: Play version = 2.4.x

Comment: Uploading files inside the application directory is not recommended. What will happen when you need to deploy your app again? You will have to worry about the files (uploaded images) that are at the same directory of the application but that aren't part of application code. My recommendation is to use an external directory and use `Ok.sendFile` to delivery the file. Also, you should be aware of [Path Traversal attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal).